# Docker compose with external postgres database and plausible

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, plausible-analytics

Hi I'm struggling to configure the docker compose to work with external postgres database on Debian 11.
It seems like the container doesn't resolve host.docker.internal correctly.
The first time I ran the container it was working because I used the IP 172.17.0.1 for the database and the container started as usual on 172.17.0.4 but each time I run docker-compose up it increment the ip (172.18.0.4 172.19.0.4 ... 172.28.0.4 ).

So the solution I've tried :

- make host.docker.internal working
- find a way to force the plausible container IP address to 172.17.0.4 and use 172.17.0.1 for the database.
- make the host mode work with localhost but that's not the most secure one

Here's the logs

```
Loading plausible..
Starting dependencies..
Starting repos..
Running migrations for Elixir.Plausible.Repo
06:57:08.578 [error] Postgrex.Protocol (#PID<0.164.0>) failed to connect: ** (DBConnection.ConnectionError) tcp connect (host.docker.internal:5432): connection refused - :econnrefused
06:57:08.578 [error] Postgrex.Protocol (#PID<0.163.0>) failed to connect: ** (DBConnection.ConnectionError) tcp connect (host.docker.internal:5432): connection refused - :econnrefused
06:57:09.988 [error] Postgrex.Protocol (#PID<0.163.0>) failed to connect: ** (DBConnection.ConnectionError) tcp connect (host.docker.internal:5432): connection refused - :econnrefused
06:57:10.343 [error] Postgrex.Protocol (#PID<0.164.0>) failed to connect: ** (DBConnection.ConnectionError) tcp connect (host.docker.internal:5432): connection refused - :econnrefused
06:57:11.505 [error] Could not create schema migrations table. This error usually happens due to the following:

  * The database does not exist
  * The "schema_migrations" table, which Ecto uses for managing
    migrations, was defined by another library
  * There is a deadlock while migrating (such as using concurrent
    indexes with a migration_lock)
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.3"

#networks:
 # lan_access:
  #  driver: bridge

services:
  mail:
    image: bytemark/smtp
    restart: always

#  plausible_db:
    # supported versions are 12, 13, and 14
 #   image: postgres:14-alpine
 #   restart: always
 #   volumes:
 #     - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
 #   environment:
 #     - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres

  plausible_events_db:
    image: clickhouse/clickhouse-server:23.3.7.5-alpine
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - event-data:/var/lib/clickhouse
      - ./clickhouse/clickhouse-config.xml:/etc/clickhouse-server/config.d/logging.xml:ro
      - ./clickhouse/clickhouse-user-config.xml:/etc/clickhouse-server/users.d/logging.xml:ro
    ulimits:
      nofile:
        soft: 262144
        hard: 262144

  plausible:
    image: plausible/analytics:v2.0
    restart: always
    command: sh -c "sleep 10 && /entrypoint.sh db migrate && /entrypoint.sh run"

    #command: sh -c "sleep 10 && /entrypoint.sh db createdb && /entrypoint.sh db migrate && /entrypoint.sh run"
    depends_on:
   #   - plausible_db
      - plausible_events_db
      - mail
   # networks:
    #  - lan_access
     # - default
   # network_mode: bridge
   # network_mode: host

    ports:
      - 8001:8000
    env_file:
      - plausible-conf.env
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
volumes:
 # db-data:
  #  driver: local
  event-data:
    driver: local
```

Here's the plausible-conf.env

```
BASE_URL=https://analytics.example.com
SECRET_KEY_BASE=SECRET
DATABASE_URL=postgres://plausible:password@host.docker.internal:5432/plausible_db
#DATABASE_URL=postgres://plausible:password@172.17.0.1::5432/plausible_db
#DATABASE_URL=postgres://plausible:password@gateway.docker.internal:5432/plausible_db
MAILER_NAME=plausible
SMTP_HOST_ADDR=localhost
SMTP_HOST_PORT=25
```

Do you know what's wrong with my configuration ?

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look original page and the code:

- https://plausible.io/docs/self-hosting
- https://github.com/plausible/hosting

Run:

```
git clone https://github.com/plausible/hosting
cd hosting

# to create secret key to paste SECRET_KEY_BASE in plausible-conf.env 
openssl rand -base64 64 | tr -d '\n' ; echo
docker-compose up -d
```

**docker-compose.yaml (that I used):**

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  mail:
    image: bytemark/smtp
    restart: always

  plausible_db:
    # supported versions are 12, 13, and 14
    image: postgres:14-alpine
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres

  plausible_events_db:
    image: clickhouse/clickhouse-server:23.3.7.5-alpine
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - event-data:/var/lib/clickhouse
      - ./clickhouse/clickhouse-config.xml:/etc/clickhouse-server/config.d/logging.xml:ro
      - ./clickhouse/clickhouse-user-config.xml:/etc/clickhouse-server/users.d/logging.xml:ro
    ulimits:
      nofile:
        soft: 262144
        hard: 262144

  plausible:
    image: plausible/analytics:v2.0
    restart: always
    command: sh -c "sleep 10 && /entrypoint.sh db createdb && /entrypoint.sh db migrate && /entrypoint.sh run"
    depends_on:
      - plausible_db
      - plausible_events_db
      - mail
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    env_file:
      - plausible-conf.env

volumes:
  db-data:
    driver: local
  event-data:
    driver: local
```

**plausible-conf.env (that I used):**

When you use the DB settings, plausible/analytics:v2.0 cannot run properly. So remove it.

```
BASE_URL=http://localhost
SECRET_KEY_BASE=AlxO9FylRkXEzARzNoYFsGQHB8ZaS1wiKt31DmnTaSYOafDopfmxmf1hyF3AF7zIsu9elF+teLRmw5DL0ZJv3Q==
```

**Running containers:**

[image]

**Browser (http://localhost:8080), it works:**

[image]

**Debugging:**

If you want to debug it, after running **docker-compose up -d**, run **docker container ls -a** to get the container id of plausible/analytics:v2.0 (e.g. a14d4b63ea97), then run **docker logs a14** to see the error/logs.

After running 'compose up' and 40 secs later, if plausible/analytics:v2.0 is restarted again and again, there is a problem on it, and view it with 'docker logs' command.

**Connection to another Postgresql container:** (this part was added after the comment)

Create a new bridge network with:

```
docker network create mynetwork
```

Add to the docker-compose.yml file:

```
networks:
  - mynetwork:

services:
 plausible_db:
   ...
   networks:
   - mynetwork
```

plausible-conf.env:

```
DATABASE_URL=postgresql://postgres:postgres@<PostgresqlContainerName>:5432/plausible_db
```

With this configuration, **plausible/analytics:v2.0** can connect the Postgresql container via the docker network.

After running, please have a look at the plausible/analytics:v2.0 container with **docker logs** .

DB connection is done (because I created plausible_db on the Postgresql container and there is no DB connection error), but there is a migration problem on the DB. I think that this is not related with the Docker network, or DB connection. It is DB migration issue.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I already have a postgres database running on my server so I wanted to use the existing one instead of creating a new one using docker compose. That's why I tryed to connecte to my database accessible at localhost:5432

Comment: I added this part "Connection to another Postgresql container" at the end of the post. I tried to fix it.  plausible/analytics:v2.0 can connect postgresql container via docker network (because now there is not any DB connection error). But I don't know the DB migration in Elixir (maybe this part is explained on the plausible web page).

Comment: Thanks for your reply that's great, it's working, but I have a real postgres installation, postgres is not running in a container.
I tried to create the bridge network and reach 172.17.0.1 or localhost or host.docker.internal but none of them worked

Comment: I finally got it running by defining a network 

networks:
   plausible_network:
      driver: bridge
      ipam:
         driver: default
         config:
           - subnet: 172.19.0.0/16
use that network and use 172.19.0.1 as host gateway for reaching the database
thanks for your help :)

Comment: your welcome :) it is good question, thank u too..